# slime-inspector-eval: how to get bindings in the inspector?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

## Long story: motivation

I have a CL code that breaks on `SORT` or `MAPCAR` with some error that a number (let's say, 25) is not a list. This tells me something is wrong with the data structure that I pass them. So, I put `(BREAK)` in the code before the place where error occurs. It looks something like this:

```
(sort
 (progn
  (break)
  (mapcar (lambda (pair)
            (list (car pair) (cdr pair)))
          (hash-table-plist (state-removed state)))
 #'<
 :key #'car)
```

(To give a bit more context, the idea here is to transform hash table `(STATE-REMOVED STATE)` into a list of pairs sorted by a key, the error is that instead of `HASH-TABLE-PLIST` I should use `HASH-TABLE-ALIST`)

Once the code hits `(BREAK)` it sends me into the debugger. At this stage I could step through the code, but I decided to inspect the `STATE`. Unfortunately, the `STATE` itself is obtained by `WITH-SLOTS`-macro from an object which is a slot in another object, and the whole function is actually generated by the `SKETCH` macro from the `sketch` library... Long story short, to get to `(STATE-REMOVED STATE)` I need to go through the layers of slot accesses in the inspector.

## TL;DR: actual question

And here is a problem: now I want to call `HASH-TABLE-PLIST` either on the object which I'm inspecting or on a slot of this object. How can I access either of them (just for comparison, in Smalltalk debugger I always have access to `self` pseudo-variable to get stuff out)? There is `slime-inspector-eval`, but how do I pass things for which I don't have explicit local bindings? Documentation on `slime-inspector-eval` doesn't say much.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, a bit more googling actually answered the question. I hope it will be of use to others.

Thanks to [this blogpost](http://puntoblogspot.blogspot.co.za/2016/08/slime-inspect-eval.html): object under inspection is bound to `*`. Also, `M-Ret` in the inspector ([`slime-inspector-copy-down`](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Inspector.html)) stores object under point in `*` so it can be used in REPL.